# Can you build upon a Xamarin UITest Query with further parameters?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uitest

In a base Page where I create common Query and result calls, I have a function that returns a built query based on Android or iOS for simplicity.

````
    ```public Query QueryById(string searchId)
    {
        Query tempQuery = null;
        if (_onAndroid)
        { tempQuery = x => x.Marked(searchId); }
        else if (_oniOS)
        { tempQuery = x => x.Id(searchId); }
        else // should never enter here
        { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

        return tempQuery;
    }```
````

Now I would like to expand a query created here say to add a
`.Index(2)` 
or a even grab all classes under that index to grab a collection of information in that original container
`.Index(3).Class("LabelRenderer")`

Is there a way I can take a query and extend it.
Something other than converting to a string, then appending everything then putting it back into a query object.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: You could try to use something like `app.Query(q => q.Id("searchId").Descendant().Index(2).Class("LabelRenderer")`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already created a query string and put it into a Query object.  
Without recreating the initial part of the string, I want to append other things.
Example:  I create ```Query newQuery = x=>x.Marked("MyGroupNameParameter")```
I can create a premade query string with a parameter and in another function get that result like ```AppResult[] = _app.WaitForElement(newQuery);```
I want another function where the tester passes an index for the group needed, I want to be able to append to a Query object without recreating.
Can I take newQuery and append .Index(x)?

Comment: You could use the `x.Marked("MyGroupNameParameter")` as parameter for the query. But if you create the newQuery and then use the index for the newQuery, it returns the value of index of the Array of AppResult (AppResult[]).

Comment: Example please, because I don't quite understand how you get down to the Class level (see above) using that.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shoule work:

```
var query = app.Query(q => q.Id("searchId")
        .Descendant()
        .Index(2)
        .Class("LabelRenderer"));
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly that isn't what I am looking for.
It may not be able... but what I am looking for is if I already have a query object created (i.e. var Query myQuery = app.Query(q=> q.Id("searchId")) for iOS or "q.Marked("searchId") for android).
Can I append to this Query object to extend it as I dive deeper?
Some reasons... I create a Query that finds a button and I can tap it with this query, but now I also want to check the text or text color or x,y coordinates or anything... 
So can I take the original Query and extend it/append to it without recreating the entire query string again.